# creating android project with eclipse 2020-09 results in wrong package tree

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm struggling with setting up an android project in eclipse (2020-09; Andmore 0.5.1).

After lots of frustrating errors and frustratingly outdated answers which didn't work, I uninstalled all android plugins form eclipse and installed Andmore only.

Now I get:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete.
Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project  MyappA
```

The (generated) code is:

```
package com.myappa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Looking closer, there is an error on the very first line:

> The declared package "com.myappa" does not match the expected package "src.com.myappa"

So my question is, why does eclipse think the expected package is **src**.com.myappa, and how can I fix it?

After all, it was eclipse that decided to generate that class in that location.

Comment: I'm gonna ask the obvious question here which is, why are you trying to use Eclipse in 2020? Android Studio is the only officially supported IDE and has been for a number of years.

Comment: @IvanWooll simple answer: I am used to eclipse where my fingers know what to do. But if eclipse fails, Android studio would be the way to go.

Comment: In the short term the switch to AS will probably give you some frustrations as is always the case when changing IDE. In the medium term you will find that there are so many things that AS does to help you in your day to day that you will be glad you switched. 
To help the transition AS has an Eclipse Key Map that you can enable

Comment: @IvanWooll so I've tried android studio without eclipse ... more same thing: creating a new project gives some mysterious error about lacking signature, can't install on virtual device. Copying and renaming existing, working proj. runs on the virtual device but does not see my real device. What I see on the net about the later takes me to tabs that don't exist or look very different. What is even more frustrating is that I was able to set up a  working project some 5 years ago with some effort, but without those problems coming not from the complexity of the app but form misbehaving tools.